# Simplest way to store data persistently server-side

Tags: javascript, php, persistent-storage

(I understand this is probably a broad subject, but I don't know enough to ask a more precise question.)
I'd like to develop a very simple web application in html and javascript. This app could be for instance a map on which users could create / edit / delete markers (CRUD).
This requires very simple data (i.e. coordinates of the markers) to be stored persistently. Since I want all users to see everybody else's marker I suppose that the data should be stored server-side. 
I would prefer to use PHP over other languages as that's what my current server supports.

What would be the simplest options to achieve this ?

Comment: You've already chosen your server-side language, all you need now is a database.  For PHP, MySQL seems like a reasonable option.

Comment: Probably read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need three things.

- PHP
- MySQL
- Google Maps Javascript API
  Check [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com)